# HTML Not Picking Up Bootstrap & Won't Combine

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating an page that allows the user to filter a dataset, hit search, and see the results update below. Whenever I updated my week function to pick_list.html instead of filter_list.html, I get the error below. My filter_list.html doesnt show any bootstrap visuals or colors from the rest of my app, just a plain list. The pick_list.html shows a search button, but no search fields and zero data.

Why am I struggling so much to combine these two?

views.py:

```
def week(request):
    #orders = Pick.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    orders = Pick.objects.all()
    #orders = week.order_set.all()
    myFilter = PickFilter(request.GET, queryset=orders)
    orders = myFilter.qs
    context = {'week':week, 'orders':orders, 'myFilter':myFilter}
    return render(request, 'app/filter_list.html',context)
```

models.py

```
class Pick(models.Model):

    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Submitter', null=True, blank=True)
    week = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Week', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name', null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Photo', null=True, blank=True)
    #photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", max_length=500, verbose_name='Photo', null=True, blank=True)
    hometown = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Hometown', null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Age', null=True, blank=True)
    progress = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Progress', null=True, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Occupation', null=True, blank=True)
    elim_week = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Week Eliminated', null=True, blank=True)
    rank = OrderField(verbose_name='Rank', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_from_object(self)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app:pick-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
```

pick_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load cms_tags %}
{% block title %} {{ title }} · {{ block.super }} {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}    

<div style="font-size:24px">
  {{ title }}
</div>

<div style="font-size:14px; margin-bottom:15px">
  Click on the arrows on the right of each contestant and drag them up or down to reorder them based on how far you think they are going to go. 
</div>

<form method="get">
  {{ myFilter.form }}
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<ul>

<table class="table table-hover" id="table-ajax" style="background-color: white;">
  <thead  style="background-color: #de5246; color:white; border-bottom:white">
    <tr>
      {% comment %} <th></th> {% endcomment %}
      <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center;"></th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:name' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:hometown' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:occupation' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:age' }}</th>
      <th>Progress</th>
      <th style="width: 160px; text-align: center;">Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="order" data-url="{% url 'cms:reorder' model_name %}">
    {% include 'app/filter_list.html' %}
  </tbody>
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

filter_list.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load cms_tags %}



{% for order in orders %}

<tr id="{{ order.id }}">
    <td><img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/files/{{ order.photo }}" width="50"/></td>
    <td><a href="" title="Leads" style="text-decoration: none">{{ order.name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ order.hometown }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.occupation }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.age }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ order.age }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm border-0 reorder" title="Reorder">
            <i class="fa fa-sort text-secondary"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% empty %}
<tr class="table-warning nosort">
    <td colspan="100%" class="text-center"><small class="text-muted">No {{ model_verbose_name_plural|lower }}</small>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr class="table-light table-sm nosort">
    <td colspan="100%"><small class="text-muted">Total rows: {{ orders.count }}</small></td>
</tr>
```

error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/picks/filter/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account',
 'cms',
 'app',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'django_cleanup',
 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Traceback error on views:

```
context 
{'myFilter': <app.filters.PickFilter object at 0x04CC9FB8>,
 'orders': <QuerySet [<Pick: Claire>, <Pick: Elizabeth>, <Pick: Cassidy>, <Pick: Eliza>, <Pick: Daria>, <Pick: Ency>, <Pick: Gabby>, <Pick: Genevieve>, <Pick: Hailey>, <Pick: Hunter>, <Pick: Hunter>]>}
myFilter    
<app.filters.PickFilter object at 0x04CC9FB8>
orders  
<QuerySet [<Pick: Claire>, <Pick: Elizabeth>, <Pick: Cassidy>, <Pick: Eliza>, <Pick: Daria>, <Pick: Ency>, <Pick: Gabby>, <Pick: Genevieve>, <Pick: Hailey>, <Pick: Hunter>, <Pick: Hunter>]>
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/picks/filter/'>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The pick_list.html shows a search button, but no search fields and
> zero data.

This is probably happening because when you include `filter_list.html` on your `pick_list.html` template, the variable `orders` is None. So when you reach the for loop at `filter_list.html`, it does not execute, so it will not return any results.

> My filter_list.html doesnt show any bootstrap visuals or colors from
> the rest of my app, just a plain list.

This is probably happening because in your `week` view you are returning `filter_list.html` directly, and inside of that template you are not extending `base.html`, so the bootstrap styles are not being applied.

> 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

This error occurs in Django when you try to do a model operation on a string, instead of a real model instance. Try to print the view context and see if you are passing models or strings.

So then, how could you fix this? Try this tutorial: https://openfolder.sh/django-tutorial-as-you-type-search-with-ajax

Comment: Added the view context from the str object error and it looks like all models - any thoughts?

Comment: "This is probably happening because when you include filter_list.html on your pick_list.html template, the variable orders is None" - can you explain why this is?

Comment: Can you please share the other view that renders `pick_list.html`?